# Python: Text localiser using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, finance, quantitative-finance

I would like to code a script that could locate a specific word or number in a financial statement. Financial statements roughly contain the same information, they are however not identical and organized in the same way. My thought is that by using Tensorflow I could train a neural network to locate the specific words or numbers for me. I am thinking that if I label different text and numbers in 1000 financial statements and use them to train the neural network, it will then be able to identify these numbers or words in all financial statements. For example, tell it in all 1000 training statements which number that is the profit of the company.

Is this doable? I have been working with coding in python for a couple of months and so far I've built some web scrapers and integrated them with twitter, slack and google sheets. I would be very grateful for all your thoughts on this project and if anyone could steer me in the right direction by sharing relevant tutorials.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Great thing that you're getting started, I believe before thinking about the actual implementation using tensorflow or any other library, you should first try to understand the  problem in regards with the basic domain of the problem itself.

I'm not really sure what are you exactly trying to achieve but to a rough idea I'm guessing it's about trying to find is a statement turns out to be a benificial to the company or not, something like of semantic analysis type of problem.

So I strongly believe that, first you should try to learn the various methodologies related to semantic analysis and find the most appropriate technique.

In short theory/understanding before the actual code.

Finally i would suggest you ask such theoratical questions on [stack exchange of AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/), here in SO we generally deal with code or something that of intermediate to code.

I hope that makes sense? ;) 
drop a comment if any doubts.

Comment: I don't want it to predict anything. I just want it to identify specific numbers or words (names) in the financial statements. The goal is to have the key information in the financial statements automatically organized in a spreadsheet without having to type it in manually. However, the name of the ceo or the amount of profit for example varies every time. Their place in the financial statement also varies. I need the neural network to figure out the right name or the right number by looking at the context, just like a human does.